# generating QueryDsl classes using querydsl-maven-plugin with groovy-eclipse-compiler

Tags: java, maven, jpa, groovy, querydsl

I'm trying to generate querydsl classes from groovy entities using alternative method described here http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.7.3/reference/html/ch03s02.html

The problem I faced with is that these classes are generated only when I do mvn compile/package twice

i.e. something with the order, classes should be generated before compilation of groovy classes

otherwise I get compilation error

```
Groovy:unable to resolve class com.application.domain.QUser
```

My pom.xml

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.1-01</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.7-01</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1-01</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-querydsl-classes</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jpa-export</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <targetFolder>target/generated-sources/java</targetFolder>
                        <packages>
                            <package>com.application</package>
                        </packages>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
```

what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

You need to:

1. Compile source Groovy code
2. Postprocess classes to generate QClasses
3. Compile generated QClasses again.

   ```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
           <artifactId>querydsl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>generate-query-dsl-classes</id>
                   <phase>process-classes</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>jpa-export</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <targetFolder>target/generated-sources/java</targetFolder>
                       <packages>
                           <package>com.my.package</package>
                       </packages>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
               <execution>
                   <id>compile-query-dsl-classes</id>
                   <phase>process-classes</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>compile</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <sourceFolder>target/generated-sources/java</sourceFolder>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   ```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work. i.e. it fails on compiling groovy code (cannot find QClasses in imports)

Comment: Yup, I forgot to mention, that you need to have your entities in a separate Maven module built before the actual project which will have "some-groovy-entities" project as dependency.